# How to add … after a particular word/character limit to the title

Tags: title

I am working on a php code as shown below:

```
   <div class="case-breaking__content">
        <p><?php echo the_title(); ?></p>
   </div>
```

The above php code returns the following content:

```
absv shss xcnx shss hshhs shhsw shshs hsnna hssnnss hssns snnss nnshs sjjjjsjsj nsnnnsns jjsnss snsnns nsnns
```

What I want is, after a particular word limit it should display ... Lets say after 8 words it should be like this;

```
absv shss xcnx shss hshhs shhsw shshs hsnna...
```

I tried in the following way but it doesn't seem to work:

```
<div class="case-breaking__content">
p><?php $out = strlen(the_title()) > 50 ? substr(the_title(),0,50)."..." : the_title(); ?></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

[`the_title()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title) prints/retrieve the title while [`get_the_title()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/) retrieve the title.

So your code should be something like this.

```
<div class="case-breaking__content">
<p>
   <?php
       $out = strlen(get_the_title()) > 50 ? substr(get_the_title(),0,50)."..." : get_the_title(); 
       echo $out;
   ?>
 </p>
</div>
```

**Note** you can use [`the_title()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title)  but it is not recommended here to keep the code clean.

```
<div class="case-breaking__content">
<p>
   <?php
       $out = strlen(the_title('', '', false)) > 50 ? substr(the_title('', '', false),0,50)."..." : the_title('', '', false); 
       echo $out;
   ?>
 </p>
</div>
```

The above code will place `...` after 50 *characters*, However if you want to place it after certain numbers of *words*, you should go for  [`wp_trim_words()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_trim_words/).

```
<div class="case-breaking__content">
   <p>
      <?php echo wp_trim_words(get_the_title(), 8, '...'); ?>
  </p>
</div>
```

I hope this may help.

Answer (score 1):

To trim by words you can use WordPress' [`wp_trim_words()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_trim_words/). Pass `get_the_title()` instead of the `the_title()` to prevent a duplicate `echo` statement.

```
<?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_title(), 8, '...' ); ?>
```